# Emotion.js with Preact SSR and RTL support

Tags: javascript, webpack, preact, emotion

I have a preact SSR app and have used Emotion JS 10 for styling.

I wanted to add RTL support with this so have used `createEmotion` and `createEmotionServer` and used the resulting `renderStylesToString` to render the app.

However while creating `createEmotion` it requires the plugins to be used for which i added the `stylis-rtl` plugin but this would always apply the RTL styles while i want the RTL styles to be applied on the basis of each request.

I could not find any way to tell emotion to apply and get the styles for RTL on each request basis.
They do have straight forward implementation for React 16 in which you can pass multiple caches for each request to the `CacheProvider`.

But i can't seem to figure this out for Preact.

One solution could be to serve different webpack builds for RTL but that would be unnecessary overhead.

EDIT 1:
for anyone looking to implement something similar, this is my approach

Client Side as well as the `css` imports on the server:

```
import stylisRTL from 'stylis-rtl';

import createEmotion from 'create-emotion';

const {
  cx: cxRTL,
  injectGlobal: injectGlobalRTL,
  css: cssRTL,
  cache: cacheRTL,
  keyframes: keyframesRTL
} = createEmotion({
  key: 'c',
  stylisPlugins: [stylisRTL]
});
const {
  cx: cxLTR,
  injectGlobal: injectGlobalLTR,
  css: cssLTR,
  cache: cacheLTR,
  keyframes: keyframesLTR
} = createEmotion({
  key: 'c',
  stylisPlugins: []
});

const runForBoth = (rtlFn, ltrFn) => (...args) => {
//this would be ur store sent in html to check whether it is in rtl or ltr mode
  const isRTL = typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.__PRELOADED_STATE__.shell.RTL;
  let result;
  if (__BROWSER__) {
    if (isRTL) {
      result = rtlFn(...args);
    } else {
      result = ltrFn(...args);
    }
  } else {
    result = ltrFn(...args);
    rtlFn(...args);
  }

  return result;
};

export const cx = runForBoth(cxRTL, cxLTR);
export const injectGlobal = runForBoth(injectGlobalRTL, injectGlobalLTR);
export const css = runForBoth(cssRTL, cssLTR);
export const keyframes = runForBoth(keyframesRTL, keyframesLTR);

export const cacheEmotionLTR = cacheLTR;
export const cacheEmotionRTL = cacheRTL;
```

and for SSR:

```
const { renderStylesToString: renderStylesToStringLTR } = createEmotionServer(cacheEmotionLTR);
const { renderStylesToString: renderStylesToStringRTL } = createEmotionServer(cacheEmotionRTL);
```

i create 2 cache and based on request headers i decide which `renderStylesToString` to use

The one concern i have is `runForBoth` is technically wrong. But it is working as of now.

I did not want to change the way `css` Fn is imported as now i can just use this custom-emotion imports and alias it in webpack

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make this per request then you should create 2 emotion instances (one with the plugin and one without it). Additionally, you would have to use correct instance for each request - the easiest way for this would be probably with context: put emotion in the context and use it from there instead of from import statement.

Comment: I have implemented something similar but am not sure if this is the correct way to do it or not?
Added the implementation in answer edit

Comment: if it works then it works, ofc this solution is slightly less optimal because you run everything twice - but with proper caching it shouldnt really matter much.